# Cannot install Odin because erase button is locked

Tags: system-installation

Cannot install Odin because the <kbd>Erase and install</kbd> is locked even though I selected boot partition, root, swap & home.

PS:

1. I have hera already installed but I marked <kbd>Format</kbd> for root, boot & home partitions but to no avail.
2. Tried to format the old root partition and it succesed but <kbd>Erase and install</kbd> is still locked.
3. When I selected Windows OS Recovery partition as my boot partition, the button got enabled. the difference between the EFI partition & the Windows OS Recovery Partition is that EFI is `fat32` & only 100MB while the Windows OS Recovery Partition is `NTFS` is 500 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the EFI partition was 100MB and this was the reason that the button was locked. the solution becomes simply to increasing the partition size to 512MiB or 550MB and it should work. notice that you will need to shift all your partitions using gparted (if you do not have a nearby empty space).

Comment: hahaha, it also happened to me in the first instance I put only 200MB and could not continue the installation. the installer should suggest the minimum size for the efi partition

Answer (score 0):

you have to select an uefi partition,
or disable first uefi on BIOS.